# Find element by ID not recognized - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a question regarding selenium,
I try to fill a form, and the id of the input text is: //input[@id='company'].
In selenium I get an error about this element not found:

```
Sun Sep 22 18:13:27 IDT 2019:ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//input[@id='company']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

This is the page element
[image]

This is my method

```
public static void inputValueById(String input,String id)
    {
        WebElement element = getWebElementByIdWithWaitToBeSeen(id);
        element.click();
        element.clear();
        element.sendKeys(input);
    }
```

the problem is that selenium not find the element, it finds it in the dev tools as you can see

Comment: Have you tried setting the program to wait for 10 seconds? Sometimes elements take their time to load.

Comment: what is `getWebElementByIdWithWaitToBeSeen`?

Comment: there might be 2 reasons why it's failing in the script. 1) your script might be trying to locate the element even before the page loaded the element or 2) the element might  be present in the iframe.

Comment: is there any frame/iframe on the page?

Comment: I try to wait 22 seconds and still not found, even I see the page loaded.  getwebElementbyudwithwait - it just wait until the id is seen, and it waits for 22 seconds and still not found the element

Comment: no Iframe in the page

Comment: Have you tried, capture a screenshot at the moment of error thrown and check element is visible or not ? may be out of area, may be because of i frame, etc can be happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
Sun Sep 22 18:13:27 IDT 2019:ERROR: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"//input[@id='company']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired element.

There are a couple of things which you need to take care:

- The [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have used isn't the **`id`**, but it's the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)
- Though you are using `chrome=76.0` but **`chromedriver=2.36`** is too old.

---

### Solution

- For the *selector* value of **`//input[@id='company']`** change the *method* as **`"xpath"`**.
- Ensure *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Ensure *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Ensure *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v77.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=77.0.3865.40/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 77.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v77.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/notes.txt))

Comment: how do you change the method? I provide an ID, but when debugging I see that the mechanism is `"css selector"`